# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

Tags: java

Я использую библиотеку `javax.mail` для отправки сообщений из под моего аккаунта с телефона Android на электронную почту:

```
Properties mProperties = new Properties();
mProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.yandex.ru");
mProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
mProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
mProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
mProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
MimeMessage mMessage = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(mProperties, new Authenticator() { //выполнение этой строки приводит к ошибке

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(yandex_username, yandex_password);
    }

}));
mMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(yandex_username + "@yandex.ru"));
mMessage.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
mMessage.setSubject(subject);
mMessage.setContent("<html><body>" + content + "</body></html>", "text/html");
Transport.send(mMessage);
```

Выполнение кода `MimeMessage mMessage = new MimeMessage(...)` приводит к ошибке:

> 01-01 06:44:54.648: V/LOG(14338): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

В проект я включил **все три** архива библиотеки, что, по идее, достаточно для работы библиотеки:

- activation.jar
- additional.jar
- mail.jar

Помогите исправить ошибку.

Находил в интернете такую же ошибку [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630002/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-mail-authenticator-whats-wrong), [тут](https://coderanch.com/t/551952/java/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-javax-mail), и, в самом деле много ссылок посетил, делал, что рекомендовали, но безрезультатно.

Comment: Покажите свой build.gradle

Comment: @Barmaley, я использую среду Eclipse. Там нет build.gradle, как в Android Studio